# How do I add additional rows in mat-table without breaking the pattern?

Tags: angular, web, frontend

I am trying to add 2 more cols (status and buttons) after `ngfor` . However, it seems it will break the entire structure (shows in the picture)

[The Broken Table Screen Shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rp8n1.png)

[I am modifying code from `material.angular.io`](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-expandable-rows)

Also I added  contains 2 more rows in `columnsToDisplays` so it will display the addtional cols.

Any suggestions on making to fix it would be appreciated!

```html
<table mat-table
       [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows
       class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Expanded Content Column - The detail row is made up of this one column that spans across all columns -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="columnsToDisplay.length">
      <div class="example-element-detail"
           [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
        <div class="example-element-diagram">
          <div class="example-element-position"> {{element.position}} </div>
          <div class="example-element-symbol"> {{element.symbol}} </div>
          <div class="example-element-name"> {{element.name}} </div>
          <div class="example-element-weight"> {{element.weight}} </div>
        </div>
        
        <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action</mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <button mat-raised-button > Accept</button>
            <button mat-raised-button > Reject</button>
          </mat-cell>
        </ngcontainer>
        
        
        <div class="example-element-description">
          {{element.description}}
          <span class="example-element-description-attribution"> -- Wikipedia </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplays"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplays;"
      class="example-element-row"
      [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
      (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element">
  </tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I forgot to add the status col in but it is same with the button part.

Comment: Do you want to add columns or rows? In title, it's "rows", in the description, it's "column"

Answer (score 0):

Add 'status' and 'button' to columnsToDisplay

```
 columnsToDisplay = ['name', 'weight', 'symbol', 'position',  'status', 'button'];
```

Add 'status' to data

```
{
    position: 1,
    name: 'Hydrogen',
    weight: 1.0079,
    symbol: 'H',
    description: `Some description`,
    status: 'Green'
  },
```

Modify table cell HTML -

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <span *ngIf="column !== 'button'"> {{element[column]}} </span>
      <span *ngIf="column === 'button'"> 
        <button>Button1</button>
        <button>Button1</button>
       </span>
         </td>
```

Updated HTML (complete)

```
<table mat-table
       [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows
       class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <span *ngIf="column !== 'button'"> {{element[column]}} </span>
      <span *ngIf="column === 'button'"> 
        <button>Button1</button>
        <button>Button1</button>
       </span>
         </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Expanded Content Column - The detail row is made up of this one column that spans across all columns -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="columnsToDisplay.length">
      <div class="example-element-detail"
           [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
        <div class="example-element-diagram">
          <div class="example-element-position"> {{element.position}} </div>
          <div class="example-element-symbol"> {{element.symbol}} </div>
          <div class="example-element-name"> {{element.name}} </div>
          <div class="example-element-weight"> {{element.weight}} </div>
        </div>
        <div class="example-element-description">
          {{element.description}}
          <span class="example-element-description-attribution"> -- Wikipedia </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;"
      class="example-element-row"
      [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
      (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element">
  </tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row"></tr>
</table>
```

Updated .ts file -

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {animate, state, style, transition, trigger} from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'table-expandable-rows-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-expandable-rows-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-expandable-rows-example.html',
  animations: [
    trigger('detailExpand', [
      state('collapsed', style({height: '0px', minHeight: '0'})),
      state('expanded', style({height: '*'})),
      transition('expanded <=> collapsed', animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)')),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class TableExpandableRowsExample {
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
  columnsToDisplay = ['name', 'weight', 'symbol', 'position',  'status', 'button'];
  expandedElement: PeriodicElement | null;
}

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
  description: string;
  status: string
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {
    position: 1,
    name: 'Hydrogen',
    weight: 1.0079,
    symbol: 'H',
    description: `Hydrogen is a chemical element with symbol H and atomic number 1.`,
    status: 'Green'
  },
  {
    position: 2,
    name: 'Helium',
    weight: 4.0026,
    symbol: 'He',
    description: `Helium is a chemical element with symbol He and atomic number 2.`,
    status: 'Green'
  },
];
```